# Solve for $f(x)$ in $b( a+f(x) )f'(x)f'(x) = c$

Tags: calculus, physics

I don't know how to solve the nonlinear differentiable equation $b( a+f(x) ) f'(x) f'(x) = c$ where $a,b,c$ are just constants and $f: [0,\infty] \to [0,\infty]$.

Comment: Is your DE this: $b(a+y)(y')^2=c?$

Comment: yes,it is , I wrote it kind of badly

Comment: It's separable: $\pm\sqrt{a+y}\,dy=\sqrt{c/b}\,dx.$

Comment: the thing is , idk how to solve differentiable ecuations , and I have this problem at physics class , so idk how it helps me

Comment: Sounds like you need to beef up your mathematics. Take Differential Equations! And Linear Algebra, if you're interested in physics.

Comment: The thing is that I am studying computer since at a Technical University and this semester alone I do physics. The differential equation course is in the next semester and linear algebra in this one , but thank you for advice!

Comment: Well, feedback for your program, then: always schedule prerequisite math courses BEFORE any physics courses that need them.

Comment: Is there something I need to add to my solution that would help?

Comment: I'm sincerely sorry for not marking your answer sooner , I'm new on the platform and  I tend to do all sort of mistakes.

Comment: Actually, what happened was that you marked my solution as the answer, and then you unmarked it. I was curious if I could improve the post, is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $y=f(x),$ and then $z=a+y,$ then $z'=y',$ and the DE simplifies to
\begin{align*}
z(z')^2&=c/b\\
\sqrt{z}\,z'&=\pm\sqrt{c/b}:=k\\
\int z^{1/2}\,dz&=k\int dt\\
\frac{z^{3/2}}{3/2}&=kt+C\\
z^{3/2}&=\frac{3kt}{2}+C\quad\text{absorb 3/2 into }C\\
z&=\left(\frac{3kt}{2}+C\right)^{\!2/3}\\
y&=\left(\frac{3kt}{2}+C\right)^{\!2/3}-a\\
&=\left(\pm\frac{3\sqrt{c}\,t}{2\sqrt{b}}+C\right)^{\!2/3}-a.
\end{align*}
You can plug this into the original DE and show that it works. Also, depending on the values of $a,b,c,$ you may be able to eliminate one of the $\pm,$ since you are requiring a non-negative function.

Comment: if the function is a function of time , the constant C is 0 ?

Comment: No, the $C$ is an arbitrary constant, which is the result of integrating (generally what you're doing when solving a DE). Most of the time, with a first-order DE like this, you'll have some initial condition that also needs to be satisfied. You choose the $C$ so that the solution I've written out satisfies the initial condition.